# What is the best method to keep a unique identifier in sync between AngularJS and database?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, api, architecture

My Angular/Node application displays a timeline of user events. The user can add, edit, and delete events.

When a new event is added, AngularJS adds the event content as JSON into a timeline array for immediate display to the user. Simultaneously AngularJS calls a Node API that inserts the event into the database and during this process the DB generates an event_id (using auto-increment).

**What is the best design to keep the event_id in sync between AngularJS and the Database (mysql)?**

Ideas:

1. I could wait for the API to return the event_id and insert that into the AngularJS timeline array. The problem here is if the user edits the event before the event_id is returned the app wouldn't know which event to update.
2. I could generate a random number (temp_id) on the AngularJS side when a new event is added and use that in the timeline array as well as send that through the API to the DB. One problem here is keeping track of two types of ID's: temp_id and event_id

Both of these ideas have downsides.

**Can someone suggest a better design?**

Comment: How about adding a transparent screen overlay in order to restrict all user events till the time that a response is received from your Node API? This can be implemented alongside Idea 1.

Comment: The both approaches have one big downside - data inconsistency. An event may not be saved in server at all because of some problems, or user can try to change/deleted not saved in server even. So, you need to use approach as  Dhruv Saxena suggested or use 1 with some kind of UI lock of event until it will be created in server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach I would consider:

Use a random `UUID` that guarantees uniqueness across clients as the primary key.

Use a session/user based auto-increment to your user/client that is not a unique key in the database.

Let Angular give your event a `temporary_id` and an `event_number`, then update that `temporary_id` once your API responds with the created event.

You may need to maintain a state of the event in your angular app until it is saved to the database. and maybe prevent the user from editing/updating that event until it is saved and your server responds.

Comment: Bishoy,

Good idea. I was thinking something similar. However, do you think using 'UUID' would create database performance issues because SQL UPDATES using the UUID column will be required when the user does edits.

I will have to research the above, but I think in this approach you can switch between doing sql updates with the auto-increment generated ID vs using the 'UUID' depending on whether the API has returned or not.


Perhaps the 'UUID' should be used on the AngularJS side and auto-increment on the database side.

Comment: Can't talk about database performance because it is affected by many other factors in your scheme and query and hosting infrastructure. But I encourage you to spike a proof of concept and performance test it